# How to create regex that allow only soem special char before and after "@"?

Tags: regex, email

Currently i'm trying to create a regex for my email.

The requirement
Before @
it allows only . and _ as spec char

After @
it allows only - and . as spec char

So far this is my regex

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\-[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
```

Correct format

- mymail@gmail.com
- my_mail@gmail.com
- my_mail.mail_mail@gmail.com
- my.mail_mail.mail@gmail.com
- my.mail_gmail.mail@gmail.com
- mymail@gmail.co.id
- mymail@gm-ail.co.id

incorrect format

- .mail@gmail
- mail.@gmail
- mail_@gmail
- _mail@gmail
- mail@-gmail
- mail@gmail-

But my regex doesn't meet some of the cases above like

1. mail.mail_mail.mail@gmil.com
2. mail_mail.mail@gmial.com

How to make the correct regex for those cases

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\_[A-Za-z0-9]+)*
```

The regex before @ is the issue i think

**EDIT**

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([._][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+(\-[A-Za-z0-9]+)* (\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
```

I change the regex like above. I think it solves the issue ?

Comment: We have a metric excrement load of email regex questions; please search before asking. Like most of the answers to those questions, your regex fails on a number of common cases. Is there a reason you are not using the regex from RFC5322?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9]+([._][A-Za-z0-9]+)*@[A-Za-z0-9]+([-\.][A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$
```